# Minitest uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am trying to run Minitest with Spec syntax with `rake test` and get this error:

```
/path/to/gem/spec/script_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant MyGem (NameError)
```

My Rakefile:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList['spec/*_spec.rb']
end
```

My file structure:

```
gem/
--lib/
----script.rb
--spec/
----script_spec.rb
--Rakefile
```

My script.rb:

```
module MyGem
  class OptionParser
    def self.option?(arg)
      arg =~ /^-{1,2}\w+$/
    end
  end
end
```

Using Minitest::Spec syntax in script_spec.rb:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

describe MyGem::OptionParser do
  describe "option?" do
    it "must be true for option name" do
      OptionParser.option?('--nocolor').assert true
    end
  end
end
```

How do I fix it? Maybe `lib` folder isn't loaded? Do I miss something related to Spec syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyGem::OptionParser` is not loaded in your tests. You either need to require it in your spec file or create a spec_helper where you require all files that you need in all your tests so you only need to `require 'spec_helper'` in your specs.

Also, since you're using the spec syntax, you will have to `require 'minitest/spec'. Your spec_helper would look something like:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'script'
```

And do this to your Rakefile so you can do `require 'script'` like above in your specs instead of doing `require_relative '../lib/script'`.

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList['spec/*_spec.rb']
end
```

Lastly, for your spec to work, add `require 'spec_helper`' at the top of your script_spec file. You'll have to do this for all your spec files and make sure to add require for all the files you need to load in your specs to your spec_helper file.

Since you're also doing spec-style testing, you might want to change your test to this:

```
MyGem::OptionParser.option?('--nocolor').must_equal true
```

You could also have code like this in your 'spec_helper' file to automatically load all files in your lib folder:

```
Dir["../lib/**/*.rb"].each do |rb_file|
  require rb_file
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't quite understand why Rake uses `t.libs` then? I think it is supposed to load all files from `t.libs` folders. By default `Rake::TestTask` adds `lib` to `libs` so there is no need to write `t.libs = ['lib']` or something similar. I tried doing it just in case and no effect.

Comment: I see. Wasn't aware of that! In that case, I will remove that line from my answer. Did my answer solve your problem though?

Comment: I think I understand now. One more question. If my `script.rb` (required in `spec_helper.rb`) requires all the rest of my gem files, should I just require it and that's it? Or I should do testing separately on different files? Whats the best practice?

Comment: If you have other files you want to test, the convention for unit tests is to have corresponding spec_files for those. That would mean you'll have to load/require each of those files in your 'spec_helper'. So if you have a file 'lib/user.rb', you'll require that in your spec_helper, `require 'user'`.

Comment: I understand that one test file normally corresponds to one file with application code. I meant that if I require one application file, which in turn requires the rest of my files, I require my whole application in end. And run all test files on it (from my spec folder), that's the right way?

Comment: You could do it that way for convenience. The Rails spec_helper is set up that way by default. You could also choose to require the individual files where they are needed on the specs if you are concerned about the speed of your specs. Shouldn't be much of a problem though to end up loading your whole app when running your specs unless your project becomes really large and you notice there's a big difference in the time it takes to run the tests.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I required my `script.rb` in `spec_helper` and required helper in test file and now I get `undefined method 'option?' for OptionParser:Class`..

Comment: Oh wait, how 'bout do `MyGem::OptionParser.option`?

Comment: That worked, thanks! But how can I avoid specifying the module?

Comment: And how do I test private methods?

Comment: I think you could do `include 'MyGem'` to avoid specifying the module namespace in your specs. To test private methods, you could do `MyGem.send(private_method)` in your specs. However, you're only supposed to test the public API of your app so it isn't advisable to test private methods.

Comment: I added `include MyGem` in `spec_helper` and it works for a file in `lib`, but for a file in `lib/options` it doesn't work. If I remove `MyGem::` from `MyGem::OptionParser`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'option?' for OptionParser:Class`.

Comment: Kindly accept my answer since it solved your problem. It would also be nice to upvote my answers in the comments that helped you out. What's the path of the file in options? It's `lib/options/script.rb`? I think in that case, you'll have to do `require 'options/script'` in your spec_helper.

Comment: `lib/options/script` is already required inside `lib/script`. Requiring it in `spec_helper` has no effect. Minitest works with `MyGem::OptionParser` in `lib/options/script` but fails with `OptionParser` with the message above.

Answer (score 2):

We are getting this error after upgrading to minitest 5.19.0 uninitialized constant MiniTest (NameError) Did you mean?  Minitest

Minitest 5.19.0 removed MiniTest class loading by default and loads only if MT_COMPAT variable is added, otherwise we need to change MiniTest to Minitest

https://my.diffend.io/gems/minitest/5.18.1/5.19.0

Comment: MiniTest != Minitest
(D'oh!)